# How android Local Service communicate with multiple activities in an application?

Tags: android

I have gone through some topics on Stackoverflow but couldnot find any sufficient answer "how multiple activities can comunicate with a bound service in android?". I am having a simple bound service in my application and 2 activities. I have established communication between service and an activity but now I have added one more activity in my application.

Activity A which is main activity will fetch some data from the service. Service is communicating with a Servlet and fetching data from servlet which I will send to my Activity A and this activity will present the data. I am invoking a new activity from activity A by clicking a button. Activity A will send some data to activity B. I am using `Intent` to share data between activity A and B. Activity B has some buttons which will update the data in Activity B and send it to Service and service will send back the response to the activity B.

I know how an activity can communicate with a Service but I dont know how a Service can communicate with 2 or more activities.

Answer (score 1):

To communicate with your `Service` in your Activity B is the same way you do it in Activity A. I assume you're registering some form of `BroadcastReceiver` that listens for things from the service in activity A. You can do that in B as well, and both activities will receive the broadcast.

If you want to send a command from Activity B to the service, you can just use your usual `startService` to send an intent back to the service. This will not restart your service, but it will just reissue a new command to the service, which you can intercept in the service by implementing the `onStartCommand` function in your service. You can read more about your Service functions with the help of this life cycle diagram, [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#LifecycleCallbacks).

So, you can either register your broadcast receiving intents in your manifest for both activities, or you can do it in code by starting to listen to the same intent filters on both activities in your onStart, and shutting them down again in your onPause.

Comment: If I dont have a BroadCastReceiver then is there any other way to communicate with service?

Answer (score 1):

If your activities extend BroadcastReceiver, they will listen for broadcasts that are sent from the application. In your service, you will need to call sendBroadcast(Intent intent) at the point when you want to communicate to your activity.

In the AndroidManifest.xml file, you will need to add intent filters to the activities you'd like your service to communicate with, which would include the action name of the intent. If you want to send different intents, I believe you need to give them different action names.

Here is an [example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html) of how to implement the such a thing.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Could you please tell me what you mean by different action names if I want to send different intents to activities?

Comment: One more question. How about if I dont want to extend my activity with  BroadcastReceiver ?

Comment: So when you create an intent, you can set an action name. Something along the lines of intent.setAction("nameofyouraction"). For example, you have Activity A and B. Activity A wants to listen for intents named "activityAaction", and Activity B listens for "activityBaction". When you create A's intent, you call intent.setAction("activityAaction"), and so on. In your AndroidManifest file, you need to register that action name to ActivityA. You can create an inner class (inside your activity) that extends BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: I am not extending my activities with BroadcastReceiver. So I will not receive broadcast messages. Is there any other way rather than BroadcastReceiver. May be with handlers or something else ?

Comment: Your activity doesn't have to extend BroadcastReceiver, you can make an anonymous class of a broadcast receiver, and then start listening in on it.